# Select related of selected related

Tags: python, django, orm

Say I have a relationship (by foreign key) like this: *Model 1 → Model 2 → Model 3*. Can I follow foreign key relationship with `select_related()` more than one level deep? I.e. not only from *Model 1* to *Model 2* but also from *Model 2 to Model 3*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, by using the normal double-underscore syntax - as [explicitly described](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in the documentation:

```
Model1.objects.select_related('model2__model3')
```